# Charles still only showing requests from one host even though Focused Hosts in unchecked?

Tags: charles-proxy

In the Charles proxy, I at some point install the root certificate for the iOS simulator and set `http://localhost:8080` in Focused Hosts to reduce clutter and only see web traffic from my local host.

In order to undo this, however, in **View > Focused Hosts...** I've unchecked and removed that entry:

[image]

The problem is that in Charles Proxy, I'm still only seeing requests to the `localhost` when come from an iOS simulator:

[image]

I do have 'Mac OS proxy' enabled in the **Proxy** menu:

[image]

If I go to a different domain in my Chrome web browser, I don't see any requests showing up in Charles, even if I go to `localhost:8080` in my browser. If I go to a different domain in the Safari app on the iPhone emulator, I don't see anything show up either, although I do see the requests if I browse to `localhost:8080` in the Safari app on the emulator.

In short, I seem to only be able to see requests to `localhost:8080` from the iOS emulator, not requests from my Chrome browser or to different domains, despite that I've 'reset' Focused Hosts. How can I make Charles Proxy see other requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, **View > Focused Hosts** is not the right menu for this; I had to go to **Proxy > Recording Settings > Include** and uncheck `localhost:8080`:

[image]

I also found it necessary to restart Charles after changing this.